# Vector Analysis- Curves in Space

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, curves

[image]

[image]

I have attached both the problem and approach to the solution. But I am confused how to proceed. Kindly help in providing the simplified version of the solution.

PS- I tried pasting the problem and solution from a word file, but I don't understand why the editor is not accepting my text. That's why I have attached the images.

Comment: First. Don't paste in the answer; this is your question. Second, what do you mean you're confused how to proceed. The solution is quite complete. What do you mean by a simplified version? You can download my free differential geometry text, linked in my profile. This result is also proved in there.

Comment: I mean I am not able to understand the steps given. @Ted I went through the proof given in your text. But still I have not understood the steps given in it. That's why if you can simplify the steps or post them here, it would help...

Comment: No, you have to study math with paper and pencil, working every step yourself. When there is a specific step you cannot explain or understand, ask about that specific step.

Comment: @Robert Lewis grateful if you can help me in simplifying the steps in this problem just like you did in another problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at all sure that the following remarks are in any real sense a simplification of the argument given in our OP Sanket Garud's question and answer, but perhaps I can expand upon the essential points and thus provide some clarification.

Given a unit speed curve $\gamma(s)$ in $\Bbb R^3$, where $s$ is the arc-length, its *unit tangent vector* $T(s)$ is defined *via*

$T(s) = \dot \gamma(s); \tag 1$

the *unit normal vector* $N(s)$ and curvature $\kappa(s)$ are defined by the [first Frenet-Serret equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas)

$\dot T = \kappa N, \; \vert N \vert = 1, \; \kappa(s) > 0; \tag 2$

we also have the *unit binormal vector*

$B(s) = T(s) \times N(s); \tag 3$

with the hypothesis $\tau(s) = 0$, the third Frenet-Serret equation yields

$\dot B(s) = -\tau(s) N(s) = -(0)N(s) = 0; \tag 4$

that is, $B(s)$ is constant along $\gamma(s)$; we thus adopt the shorthand

$B = B(s); \tag{4.5}$

in accord with the definition (3) we have

$B \cdot N(s) = T(s) \times N(s) \cdot N(s) = 0 \tag 5$

and

$B \cdot T(s) = T(s) \times N(s) \cdot N(s) = 0. \tag 6$

Now everything which has been written in the above is either a well-known and accepted fact of elementary differential geometry or has been covered by our OP in his question/answer.  We next deviate from the presented work of Sanket Garud and observe that (1) implies

$\gamma(s) - \gamma(s_0) = \displaystyle \int_{s_0}^s T(u) \; du, \tag 7$

whence

$B \cdot (\gamma(s) - \gamma(s_0)) = B \cdot \displaystyle \int_{s_0}^s T(u) \; du = \int_{s_0}^s B \cdot T(u) \; du = \int_{s_0}^s 0 \; du = 0, \tag 8$

which shows that $\gamma(s) - \gamma(s_0)$ lies in a plane normal to $B$; thus

$\gamma(s) = (\gamma(s) - \gamma(s_0)) + \gamma(s_0) \tag{8.5}$

lies in the plane normal to $B$ and containing $\gamma(s_0)$; furthermore, in accord with (5) and (6), both $T$ and $N$ lie in, are tangent to, this plane at every $\gamma(s)$; thus the vector

$C(s) = \gamma(s) + \dfrac{1}{\kappa}N(s) \tag 9$

lies in this plane as well, since $N(s)$ does; we have

$\dot C(s) = \dot \gamma(s) + \dfrac{1}{\kappa} \dot N(s) = \dot \gamma(s) + \dfrac{1}{\kappa} \dot N(s)$
$= T(s) + \dfrac{1}{\kappa} (-\kappa T(s) + \tau B(s)) = T(s) + \dfrac{1}{\kappa}(-\kappa T(s)) = T(s) - T(s) = 0; \tag{10}$

thus,

$C(s) = C \tag{11}$

is constant, and (9) becomes

$\gamma(s) = C - \dfrac{1}{\kappa}N(s); \tag{12}$

thus,

$\vert \gamma(s) - C \vert = \left \vert \dfrac{1}{\kappa} N(s) \right \vert = \dfrac{1}{\kappa} \vert N(s) \vert = \dfrac{1}{\kappa}, \tag{13}$

which shows that $\gamma(s)$ lies in the circle of radius $1/\kappa$ centered at $C$ in the plane normal to $B$ containing $\gamma(0)$.  We note that if $\gamma(s)$ is not restricted to lie in this plane, then (13) still binds but now tells us that
$\gamma(s)$ lies in the sphere with the same radius and center.  Since both the circle and sphere described by (13) are of the same radius $1/\kappa$, the circle is in fact a great circle in this sphere.

Comment: That was what I was looking for! I have now understood all the steps in the solution. Thank you @Robert

Comment: @SanketGarud:  Thanks for the kind words.  If you really find my answer helpful, you might consider upvoting/accepting (green checkmark) it.  ***Cheers!***

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The approach to problem solution is attached. Kindly help in providing the simplified version of the solution.